# Why is the sum of currents in a diode constant?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, semiconductor-physics, electronics

Why is the sum of currents in a diode constant?
Please answer my question I'm very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Charge conservation. The diode is not creating any net charge, so the current that flows into the diode has to be the same as the current that flows out. Any components of the current in the diode must sum to this same current.

Comment: In steady state, yes. There may be transients to account for.

Answer (score 0):

For a doped semiconductor, the number of electrons in conduction band depends on the temperature of the semiconductor and also, the voltage across the semiconductor. It depends on the amount of doping also, but that is fixed at the time of manufacture. So addition of more electrons into the p side would increase the electron concentration above equilibrium value. If we see, The p side is actually capable of accepting the electrons injected from n side. So it is reasonable to expect that sum of currents is not constant. But as electrons are added to p side, the concentration increases above equilibrium value. This prevents electrons from merging with p side and thus all added electrons come out.

This is more a Le chatlier's principle than charge conservation